# Swift - search duplicate in multidimensional array - sudoku

Tags: arrays, swift, matrix, multidimensional-array, sudoku

I'm creating a 4x4 sudoku game in a multidimensional array filled by random generated numbers (from 1 to 4). Now I have to search duplicates and replace them with other random numbers until there are unique numbers on the single row, single column and on the four 2x2 sub-matrix.
How can I do that?

There's my code for generating the grid:

```
func fill (N:Int) {
    for row in 0..<N {
        //Append an empty row
        matrix.append([Int]())

        for _ in 0..<N {
            //Populate the row
            matrix[row].append(Int(arc4random_uniform(4)+1))
        }
    }
}

fill(N: 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the array into a set(removes duplicates) and then back into an array. **But** your order might change.

```
matrix = Array(Set(matrix))
```

Comment: Forgot then you add the numbers and repeat until there are no duplicates, presumably by counting the array and making sure it has the right number of elements.